# List in Mysql tables that do not have AVG

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL like this:

```
LOCAL

id | name


GRADE (grades given by users for each location)

id | id_local | grade
```

When I list the average grade each local received, and the local has not yet received any grade, it does not appear in the list

My code is like this

```
SELECT *, AVG(grade.grade) AS 'grade' FROM local
LEFT JOIN grade ON local.id = grade.id_local
GROUP BY grade.id_local
```

Comment: What are notes (there is no mention of them in your query) and where do they live?

Comment: @P.Salmon: I'd guess "note" should be synonym with "grade" here.

Comment: @sticky bit never assume...

Comment: @P.Salmon, sorry, it is grade, my english is not so good.

Comment: `SELECT * .. GROUP BY grade.id_local` is in 99% of the cases wrong [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) usage unless the results are [functionally dependent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) on `grade.id_local`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are grouping by `grade.id_local`, and when a location has no grades, that is a `NULL` value. You should be grouping by `local.id` instead. Also you might want to apply `COALESCE` to your `AVG` value to make it 0 when there are no grades.

```
SELECT local.id, local.name, 
       COALESCE(AVG(grade.grade), 0) AS 'grade' 
FROM local
LEFT JOIN grade ON local.id = grade.id_local
GROUP BY local.id
```

Output (for my demo):

```
id  name    grade
1   here    4.5
2   there   0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w4FqUR5zq7anKK5hzPMwbP/0)

Answer (score 2):

You need to aggregate by columns in the *first* table:

```
SELECT l.*, AVG(g.grade) AS grade
FROM local l LEFT JOIN
     grade g
     ON local.id = g.id_local
GROUP BY l.id;
```

The `GROUP BY` is okay even with `SELECT l.*`, assuming that `id` is unique or a primary key in `local` (a reasonable assumption).

Comment: Very true see [Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html).. Functional Dependence is a SQL:1999+ standard which is optional not every database supports this, which is also mentioned [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) in the manual